# Error:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.ViewOnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, xml

## Motor.java

```
package dnvp.pm7a1.motorbluethoot;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

//////////////////////////////////
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
//////////////////////////////////

public class Motor extends AppCompatActivity {

    //widgets
    Button BTNenviar, BTNAmbos, BTNDerecha;
    Button Desconectar, BTNIzquierda, Apagar, OFF, ON;
    TextView Dato;
    int min, second2;
    String Cadena;
    Handler bluetoothIn;
    final int handlerState = 0;
    BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder DataStringIN = new StringBuilder();
    private ConnectedThread MyConexionBT;
    // Identificador unico de servicio - SPP UUID
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    // String para la direccion MAC
    private static String address = null;
    //-------------------------------------------
    Intent btEnablingIntent;
    int requestCodeForeEnable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //2)
        ////////////////////////////////////
        BTNAmbos = findViewById(R.id.BTNambos);
        BTNenviar  = findViewById(R.id.BTNenviar);//
        /*button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });*/
        /////////////////////////////////// Enlaza los controles con sus respectivas vistas
        BTNIzquierda = findViewById(R.id.BTNizquierda);
        Desconectar = findViewById(R.id.IDdesconectar);
        Dato = findViewById(R.id.IDbufferin);
        myBluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        OFF = findViewById(R.id.btnOFF2);
        ON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnON);

        btEnablingIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        requestCodeForeEnable = 1;
        //Dato.setText("Conectado");
        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    DataStringIN.append(readMessage);

                    int endOfLineIndex = DataStringIN.indexOf("#");

                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                        String dataInPrint = DataStringIN.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                        Dato.setText("Dato: " + dataInPrint);//<-<- PARTE A MODIFICAR >->->
                        DataStringIN.delete(0, DataStringIN.length());
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_motor);
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // get Bluetooth adapter
        VerificarEstadoBT();

        // Configuracion onClick listeners para los botones
        // para indicar que se realizara cuando se detecte
        // el evento de Click
        BTNIzquierda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                MyConexionBT.write("0");
                Dato.setText("Izquierda");
            }
        });
        BTNAmbos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                MyConexionBT.write("1");
                Dato.setText("Ambos");
            }
        });

        BTNAmbos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                MyConexionBT.write("1");
                Dato.setText("Ambos");
            }
        });


       /*BTNenviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               MyConexionBT.write(";"+Cadena);
               Dato.setText("Derecha");
           }
       });}*/

        Apagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyConexionBT.write("0");
                Dato.setText("Apagado");
            }
        });

        Desconectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (btSocket!=null)
                {
                    try {btSocket.close();}
                    catch (IOException e)
                    { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                }
                finish();
            }
        });
        bluetoothONMethod();
        bluetoothOFFMethod();
    }
    private void bluetoothOFFMethod() {
        OFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                    myBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*@Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int minute, int second) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timetext);
        textView.setText("Minutos: " + minute + "   Segundos:" + second );
        minute = min;
        second = second2;
        //int tmpInt = 10;
        String minu = Integer.toString(min);
        String segundo = Integer.toString(second2);
        //min = Integer.valueOf(minute.getText().toString());
        Cadena = "" + minu +segundo;
    }*/

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException
    {
        //crea un conexion de salida segura para el dispositivo
        //usando el servicio UUID
        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //Consigue la direccion MAC desde DeviceListActivity via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //Consigue la direccion MAC desde DeviceListActivity via EXTRA
        address = intent.getStringExtra(DispositivosBT.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);//<-<- PARTE A MODIFICAR >->->
        //Setea la direccion MAC
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try
        {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La creacción del Socket fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establece la conexión con el socket Bluetooth.

        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MyConexionBT = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        MyConexionBT.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        try
        { // Cuando se sale de la aplicación esta parte permite
            // que no se deje abierto el socket
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {}
    }

    private void bluetoothONMethod()
    {
        ON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)

            {
                if(myBluetoothAdapter==null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                    {
                        startActivityForResult(btEnablingIntent, requestCodeForeEnable);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Comprueba que el dispositivo Bluetooth Bluetooth está disponible y solicita que se active si está desactivado
    private void VerificarEstadoBT() {

        if(btAdapter==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "El dispositivo no soporta bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }



    //Crea la clase que permite crear el evento de conexion
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread
    {
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            try
            {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Se mantiene en modo escucha para determinar el ingreso de datos
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Envia los datos obtenidos hacia el evento via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //Envio de trama
        public void write(String input)
        {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(input.getBytes());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //si no es posible enviar datos se cierra la conexión
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La Conexión fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## activity_motor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/grad_bg"
    tools:context=".Motor">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTNenviar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="289dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="334dp"
        android:text="Derecha" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTNizquierda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="339dp"
        android:text="Izquierda" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/IDcontrol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Seleccionar Tiempo"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTNambos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="176dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:text="Ambos" />



    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/IDbufferin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="195dp"
        android:text="Dato:"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/IDdesconectar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="101dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:text="DESCONECTAR"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Si alguien me puede apoyar se los agradecería :)

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar algo? Nos pones un error en el título, un montón de líneas de código y ya.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, no has inicilizado todos los botones, por lo que no puedes crearles ningún listener. Tienes un "Button Apagar" que no has buscado en tu XML, pero le has tratado de añadir el evento de onClick.

Comment: Gracias Iñigo Me recuerdas como inicializar los botones?

Comment: Tal y como tienes en el código con otros botones:BTNAmbos = findViewById(R.id.BTNambos);

Comment: Segun yo la unica que me faltaba inicializar es la de Apagar, de ahi en mas estoy revisando nuevamente el codigo y me parece que no me falta alguna otra, aunque casualmente acabo de correr otra vez y me sigue marcando el error en la siguiente linea BTNIzquierda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Prueba a añadir setContentView(R.layout.activity_motor); debajo de super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Así estaba originalmente, lo cambie de lugar para ver si daba algún resultado, pero manda error durante la ejecución también

Comment: Ya lo solucione por si acaso regrese el setContentView(R.layout.activity_motor);  a su posicion original debajo de super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); (aunque con esto no se soluciono) sin embargo lo que si dio resultado fue el comentar lo siguiente //bluetoothONMethod();
        //bluetoothOFFMethod();

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo Iñigo